# Skipping a test in Cypress conditionally

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

I'm trying to find out if I'm able to conditionally skip a test `it()` in my test suite and deal with its async nature as well.

I've read about conditional testing in Cypress docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html and also mochajs documentation about it https://mochajs.org/.

My intention is to check if an error is displayed on a website, and skip the test if it does. Otherwise continue with the assertions.

The code snippet from mochajs that I'm trying to take to my test in Cypress is:

```
it('should only test in the correct environment', function() {
  if (/* check test environment */) {
    // make assertions
  } else {
    this.skip();
  }
});
```

So what I've got in Cypress is:

```
it('shows the list', function() {
    if (queryFailed()) {
      this.skip();
    } else {
      cy.get('.list')
        .should('be.visible')
    }
```

Note that I changed the arrow function in my `it()` to be a `function()` so that I can make use of `this`.

`queryFailed()` is a function that checks if the query succeeded or not.

```
function queryFailed() {
  cy.get('.spin')
    .then($container => {
      const htmlLoaded = $container[0].innerHTML;

      if (htmlLoaded.indexOf('List') !== -1) {
        return false;
      }

      if (htmlLoaded.indexOf('error') !== -1) {
        return true;
      }

      cy.wait(1000);
      queryFailed();
    });
}
```

Briefly, if the content of the `div` element I'm waiting for has "error" then I know the query failed so I return true, otherwise I return false.

What I see in my tests after debugging, is that even though the condition works well, the async nature of JS executes the code in the `else` statement at the same time than the `if`. So the final output is as if there is no condition at all, since everything is tested.

Is there a better way of dealing with this async feature of JS?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you are almost there, but instead of the synchronous `if () {...} else {...}` pattern you need the asynchronous callback pattern.

```
it('shows the list', function() {

  const whenFailed = function() {
    this.skip()
  }

  const whenSucceeded = function() {
    cy.get('.list').should('be.visible')
  }

  queryFailed(whenFailed, whenSucceeded);
}

function queryFailed(whenFailed, whenSucceeded) {
  cy.get('.spin')
    .then($container => {
      const htmlLoaded = $container[0].innerHTML;

      if (htmlLoaded.indexOf('List') !== -1) {
        whenSucceeded();
        return;
      }

      if (htmlLoaded.indexOf('error') !== -1) {
        whenFailed();
        return;
      }

      cy.wait(1000);
      queryFailed(whenFailed, whenSucceeded);
    });
}
```

---

However, I note the recursive call to `queryFailed()`, which looks like you are manually retrying the content of the spin container.

Cypress has built in retries, so all you have to do is decide on a maximum time your result will possibly take (say 20 seconds), and it will conclude the command as soon as the desired content arrives, or fail the test altogether if it doesn't happen in 20 seconds.

Also, you should be in control of the success/failure of whatever the spinner is waiting on (e.g fetching the list via XHR). So you should split the test into two - one for success and one for failure.

```
context('when the list loading succeeds' function() {

  it('shows the list', function() {
    // Mock XHR success here
    cy.contains('.spin', 'List', { timeout: 20000 });
    cy.get('.list').should('be.visible');
  })

  it('does not show an error message', function() {
    ...
  })

})

context('when the list loading fails' function() {

  it('does not show the list', function() {
    // Mock XHR failure here
    cy.contains('.spin', 'error', { timeout: 20000 });
    cy.get('.list').should('not.be.visible');
  })

  it('shows an error message', function() {
    ...
  })

})
```

This is a bit rough as I don't know the exact HTML expected, or what the spinner is waiting on, but you can see this pattern is much tidier and tests all paths in a controlled manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer, it works for me! I only had to change the `whenFailed` function definition to be an arrow function, so that `this` would have the context of the `it`.

Comment: How can we achieve the same in Cypress Cucumber?

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for the detailed description!
I provide you a solution for your very first question

> I'm trying to find out if I'm able to conditionally skip a test it() in my test suite and deal with its async nature as well.

Use an environment variable, I report you a solution of mine (actually using in my pipeline).

```
if (!Cypress.env("SKIP_E2E_TESTS")) {
  it(...);
}
```

and in my `package.json` file I have a script that looks like this

```
"test": "CYPRESS_SKIP_E2E_TESTS=true npm-run-all --parallel --silent test:unit test:cypress",
```

My goal was the same as yours, I'd like to disable some tests in some circumstances (the CI pipeline in my case).

So put the whole test into a condition instead of having a conditional test.

Let me know if you need some more help

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand that in your case, you want to pass on if you desire to skip the test beforehand, right? In my case, I intend to do it depending on a condition that happens at runtime (I know it's dangerous but it's a tricky case :)

Comment: > Thank you for the answer! I understand that in your case, you want to pass on if you desire to skip the test beforehand, right?

Yes, you are right sorry :)

Answer (score 14):

Note the library [@cypress/skip-test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test) has archived. Please check other solutions.

> This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 31, 2023. It is now read-only.

---

Cypress now also provides a library [@cypress/skip-test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test) which can give more controls by

- `cy.skipOn`
- `cy.onlyOn`
- `isOn`
- boolean flag
- headed / headless environments
- ENVIRONMENT

Comment: Can we pass custom message in skipOn and in my case it is not coming in to cy keyword, i have to import the skip-test in each class :/

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan - You can use `cy.log("message")` to provide a custom message.

Answer (score 7):

I am using an adapted version of @NoriSte's answer that still registers the tests, but as skipped:

```js
const maybeDescribe = Cypress.env('SOME_ENV_VAR') ? describe : describe.skip

maybeDescribe('Test suite', function() { /* ... */ })
```

and then similarly, on CI, where I want to skip the tests:

```sh
export CYPRESS_SOME_ENV_VAR=
$(npm bin)/cypress run
```

My source-controlled [`cypress.json`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-1-cypress-json) has `SOME_ENV_VAR` defined so when I run locally, the tests are not skipped.

Answer (score 4):

Your `queryFailed()` returns either `true` or `false` depending on container `cy.get('.spin')` child that eventually appears having text "List" or "error".

So you can search for both at once, one or the other will turn up.

Using ***two selectors in one query***, separated by a comma - you defer the conditional check until the async elements have resolved.

```js
cy.get('.spin')
  .find(':contains("List"), :contains("error")')      // retry until one appears
  .then($el => {
    if ($el.contains("List")) {
      // assertions about List
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think to answer this correctly, we need to distinguish two use cases

- Temporarily disable parts of the test (for debugging)
- Run Cypress statements conditionally

The following sections will address both topics.

---

#### Temporarily disable parts of your code (for debugging)

There is a simple way cypress allows this directly in your code:

- If you want to temporarily run just one part of a test, you can use

  ```
  .only(...) // will only execute this part
  ```
- if you want to skip a test, use

  ```
  .skip(...) // will skip this part
  ```

You can use them after `describe` or after `it`. Insert them like:

```
describe.skip("Test 1", () => { 
    // ... 
})

describe.only("Test 1", () => { 
    // ... 
})
```

or:

```
it.only("Navigate to a web page", () => { ... })   
it.skip("Change data", () => { ... })
```

After you're done, just remove the `.skip` and `.only` and the complete tests will run again as designed. Note this is useful while debugging the tests and skip / exclude / run them while testing. It is not meant for conditional execution (i.e. let the test itself decide which parts to run).

---

#### Run statements conditionally

##### 1. Using `if` statements

A different way is to use JavaScript features to control the flow of your test (if conditions, putting functions around your test parts & comment out the function calls you want to skip etc).

For example:

```
if (Cypress.config('viewportWidth') > 350) {

  it('does not run on mobile viewports', () => {
    // ...
  });

}
```

As described [here](https://filiphric.com/skip-test-conditionally-with-cypress). For this purpose (i.e. conditional statements) also a plugin exists (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63660035/1016343)), but is "archived", meaning no longer maintained.

##### 2. Writing your own Cypress command

Last, not least, you can write your own extension named **`runIf`** like so:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('runIf', (condition, fn) => {
    if (condition !== undefined && condition === true 
        && fn!==undefined && fn!==null && typeof fn === 'function') {
        cy.wait(1).then(($sel) => { (fn)($sel) })
    }
})
```

and copy it into the file `command.js` (which is in the `support` folder).

Then you can use it in your code like:

```
cy.runIf(a===5, () => { 
    cy.log("The variable a has the value 5") 
})
```

Note that constants or variables you defined outside are easily accessible as closure, like

```
const user_name = "Sarah Connor"

cy.runIf(user_name!=="", () => {
    cy.log(`Hello ${user_name}!`)
})

cy.runIf(user_name==="", () => {
    cy.log("No user defined")
})
```

---

Regarding the case you've shown in the question, you could use it like:

```
cy.runIf(!queryFailed(), () => {
  cy.get('.list')
    .should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: you can also write xit(...) instead of it.skip(...)

And if you want cypress to execute only one test file, you can do this like so (for component tests):

cypress run --spec "path/to/your/test.component.cy.ts" --component

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as I understand it. Don't see an example of using .only or .skip with a condition (ie. async operation with cy.request or something else..)

Comment: @trainoasis - Added some more examples, I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Same example as Hongbo Miao gave (the plugin is marked as archived).

Comment: @Bypass - There is also a way to create and use your own Cypress command, I have added an example.

Comment: @Bypass - To reduce redundancy, I replaced the reference to the plugin by a link to Hongbo Miao's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the Mocha `skip` function because Cypress uses Mocha internally. Access Mocha context using `cy.state('runnable').ctx`, and call `skip()` on that.

In TypeScript:

```
// @ts-ignore "cy.state" is not in the "cy" type
export const getMochaContext = () => cy.state('runnable').ctx as Mocha.Context;
```

Example usage in a test, you'll see the test as skipped and the obvious assertion error after the `skip()` is not reported.

```
it("should be skipped", () => {
  getMochaContext().skip();
  expect(0).to.equal(1);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) contains a few workflows for conditionally running tests in CI and altered workflows for mobile viewports, for instance.

In addition, as of Cypress v4.8.0 certain [Test Configurations](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Test-Configuration) may be applied to a suite or individual test.

For instance:

```
it('Show warning outside Chrome', {  browser: '!chrome' }, () => {
  cy.get('.browser-warning')
   .should('contain', 'For optimal viewing, use Chrome browser')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

We are using an adapted version by Ben Mosher

```
const maybeDescribe = Cypress.config("baseUrl") === "https://your-env-url/" 
? describe 
: describe.skip
   
maybeDescribe('Test something... or not dunno', function() { /* */ })
```

Seems to work for the Github workflow that run tests as well.

Answer (score -1):

The up-to-date way is via [@cypress/skip-test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test). However, the usage for me with cypress v10 and TypeScript was slightly different than in the readme:

`yarn add --dev @cypress/skip-test`

No further setup needed, simply in the spec:

```js
import { skipOn } from '@cypress/skip-test'

describe('something', () => {
  skipOn(Cypress.env('mySetting') === 'settingValue', () => {
    it('can do something', () => {
      // ...
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: The repo "has been archived by the owner on Jan 31, 2023."  It should still work but, not sure if there's a recommended alternative.