# Skip cypress test based on response of a request

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I need a way to skip a test block in Cypress based on the evaluation of IF/ELSE condition. Below is the code that I have

```
it("Website testing",function(){
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/isIPv6",
            timeout:300000
        }).then(network_result => {
            cy.log(network_result.body)
            if(network_result.body.isIPv6 == false)
            {
               statements
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log("IPv6 device, stopping the test")
                this.skip()
             }
         })
})
```

the above code snippet dosent work because `this.skip()` is a synchronous statement, and cypress gives error for it.

I have also tried `it.skip()`, `throw()` but its not useful in this case.
I need a method wherein I could skip the test execution/block when execution control comes to else block, and send the test to skipped/pending state.

Comment: You can check this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530318/skipping-a-test-in-cypress-conditionally

Answer (score 1):

I see you have the `it(title, function() {...}` pattern which allows access and modification to `this`, but you probably also need to apply it to the callback in `.then()`

```js
it("Website testing", function() {
  cy.request({
    ...
  }).then(function(network_result) {
    ...
    else {
      ...
      this.skip()
    }
  })
})
```

---

Just noticed the `skip()` is inside the `it()`, but you should skip the test before `it()` starts, so possibly

```js
beforeEach(function() {
  cy.request({
    ...
  }).then(function(network_result) {
    ...
    else {
      ...
      this.skip()
    }
  })
})

it('skipped if the beforeEach calls "this.skip()"', () => {
  ...
})
```