# How to skip a Cypress test based on an IF ELSE statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I want to skip a test case based on the IF ELSE statement. I'm sharing the code below but although it couldn't find the element **rather than skipping**, **it's failing** the test case then continues with the following tests. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve skipping?

Thanks in advance!

```
it('verifies the release carousel', function () {
      cy.get("body").then($body => {
        //Checks whether release carousel is displayed and acts accordingly
        if ($body.find('[data-cy="release-heading"]').length > 0) {
          loginPage.releaseHeader()
                    .should('be.visible');

          loginPage.releaseImage()
                   .should('be.visible');

          loginPage.releaseTitle()
                   .should('be.visible');
        } else {
          this.skip()
      }})
    })
```

**Note:** I also checked this topic [Skipping a test in Cypress conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530318/skipping-a-test-in-cypress-conditionally) and tried to edit my code as mentioned in the 1t answer but couldn't achieve :(

I asked ChatGPT too, which suggested using `Cypress.runner.stop();` and this stops the whole test though.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54541948/22438867) is a good one but the scenario is a bit complicated. Use the same pattern but check your conditional statement with the console.

I would add the visibility test into the `if()` statement, because at the moment you only have an *existence* condition.

```js
it('verifies the release carousel', function () {

  //Checks whether release carousel is displayed
  const releaseHeadingVisible = Cypress.$('body')
    .find('[data-cy="release-heading"].is(":visible")').length > 0;

  console.log(releaseHeadingVisible)      // check and adjust condition

  if (!releaseHeadingVisible) {
    this.skip()
  }

  loginPage.releaseHeader().should('be.visible');
  loginPage.releaseImage().should('be.visible');
  loginPage.releaseTitle().should('be.visible');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Aladin for the suggestion! This worked perfectly and solved the problem.